# How to dynamically load properties from a file in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm scripting my build process, and I'd like to have a single MSBuild script that clones a repo, then includes properties in a file in that repo to drive the build. The only way I've found to include properties from another file is with the `Import` task, which can't reside inside a `Target`, so the file it's importing has to exist when MSBuild is initially invoked. Is there any way to run the `Import` after a target has run, or another way altogether to get properties out of a file in the middle of a build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make two separate calls to my script in the BAT script that invokes it. The first calls my Clone task, which creates the properties file. The second calls the tasks that require those properties. I made sure the `<Import>` task has a conditional requiring the file to exist. I'm still open to a cleaner approach, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call ["msbuild" task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task) to run another msbuild process for same project with specific params (path to .props file for example).

```
<Target Name="Default">
    <MSBuild 
         Projects="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)"
         Properties="ParamsPath='./ParamsPath/name.props"
         Targets="DoSomethingTarget"/>
</Target>
<Import Project=$(ParamsPath) Condition="Exists('$(ParamsPath)')"/>
<Target Name="DoSomethingTarget">
    <DoSomeThingTasks/>
</Target>
```

But Im sure that "the right tool for right the job". Maybe you should look at solutions such as FAKE, PSake, Cake?